# Jquery undefined error for getting attribute of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
 <a id="1" href"javascript:void(0)" onclick="myfunc();" class="a">click</a>


 myfunc(){
    var $id=$(this).attr('id');
    console.log($id);

  }
```

I am getting undefined error ... and can't figure it out.
can any one tell me what is happing?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You also don;t need that javascript:void(0)

Comment: Are your quotations closed in real code?

Comment: Your code is missing all kinds of things... `"`, `=` and more...

Comment: Are any other errors being reported? The snippet you listed appears to include a syntax error lacking a keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*.js

```
$(document).on("click",".a",function(){
console.log($(this).attr("id")); 
});
```

Using jquery you can handle when the element is clicked and get any attribute with `$(this).attr("attribute")`

*.html

```
<a id="1" href"javascript:void(0)" class="a">click</a>
```

Comment: thank you! it does the job! but i am surprised what is my problem... can you explain just for ...

Comment: as you was trying you do not get the same object as my approach, see this http://jsfiddle.net/WLbYb/. I advise you to use `$(document).on(..` instead of javascript inline

Comment: [that's](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/) what I mean

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the following code which fixes your syntax. Please let me know if I am wrong assuming this:

```
<a id="1" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myfunc()" class="a">click</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunc(){
    var $id=$(this).attr('id');
    console.log($id);
}
</script>
```

Your function is actually simply calling myfunc in the global context and the `this` keyword is referencing `window` rather than the `<a>` element. To fix this, either use `onclick="myfunc.call(this)"`. The complete code is:

```
<a id="1" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myfunc.call(this)" class="a">click</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunc(){
    var $id=$(this).attr('id');
    console.log($id);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<a id="1" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myfunc()" class="a">click</a>

 myfunc(){
    var $id=$(this).attr('id');
    console.log($id);
  }
```

you were missing a ton of `""` and `=` and stuff